# Why was 以及 replaced with 和？

Tags: word-choice

Lately, I handed in a translation saying:

> 那时， 有人多次无故破坏我的电动轮椅。甚至于打断椅子扶手，打碎后视镜、在椅座上灭烟头，以及小便的程度。

After transmitting it in, I though 以及 would probably be replaced with 並且。But to my great surprise I found my professor striking 以及 and opting for 和。Is there an explanation for this? She also struck 的程度, but perhaps I should ask that separately.

From my reading [examples](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/391710652) it seems that I can always replace 和 with 以及. If anything the latter’s scope of application is slightly broader.

### TLDR

There is the possibility that she just wants to simplify the language. She also replaced 彼時 with 那時；豺狼当道之處 with 惡人橫行的地方 and a host of other similar cases.
The German original had not been colloquial, so I had Not made any effort to stay colloquial either.

Normally I just ask her; but since there is just one question session for dozens of students (who have collectively received hundreds of corrections), I thought I’d ask the cases that may have general answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> striking 以及 and opting for 和

in "[A] 以及 [B]" ([A] also [B]), [A] is the primary and [B] is the secondary,

in "[A] 和 [B]" ([A] and [B]), [A] and [B] are of equal importance

in "[A] 甚至 [B] ([A] even [B]), [B] is at a higher degree compared to [A]

Comparing 打断椅子扶手, 打碎后视镜, 在椅座上灭烟头, and 小便

小便 should be of equal importance compared to the other three, therefore, 和 is preferable to 以及

> She also struck 的程度

The word 的 turned "打断椅子扶手，打碎后视镜，在椅座上灭烟头和小便" into an adjectival phrase that modified 程度 --> (to the degree of) "打断椅子扶手，打碎后视镜，在椅座上灭烟头和小便

- 甚至于[去到]打断椅子扶手，打碎后视镜、在椅座上灭烟头，以及小便[的程度]。 --> describe the severity
- 甚至于打断椅子扶手，打碎后视镜、在椅座上灭烟头，以及小便。 --> list the damages

Comment: So, if I want to stress the severity, I should keep 的程度？

Comment: I agree that you keep "的程度", but it is better to use "甚至到了 ... 的程度". 甚至到了打断椅子扶手，打碎后视镜、在椅座上灭烟头，以及在椅座上小便的程度。

Answer (score 3):

1. Both 以及 and 和 share the meaning of "and", however, 以及 also means "as well as" and "together/along with", which is often used to refer to/linking a third person or item

- "你**和**我**以及**其他人(you **and** I **as well as** other people)" sounds better than "你**和**我**和**其他人(you **and** I **and** other people)".

Note that in the example above, 和 can replace 以及, but the reverse is not true (Incorrect - "你**以及**我**以及**其他人". Also, when there are only two persons/items involved, such as "你**和**我" can't be replaced with "你**以及**我"; and "纸**和**笔" can't be replaced with "纸**以及**笔".

2. I agree, 以及 can be replaced with 並且, and 的程度 shall be eliminated or replaced with 的情形(situation) - 在椅座上灭烟头並且小便的情形.

3)IMO, I will modify the sentence as:

- 那时， 有人多次无故破坏我的电动轮椅。**有**打断椅子扶手**的**，**有**打碎后视镜**的**、**更有**在椅座上灭烟头**甚至于**小便的(情形)。Or,
- 那时， 有人多次无故破坏我的电动轮椅。**有**打断椅子扶手**的**，**有**打碎后视镜**的**、**更有**在椅座上灭烟头**和**小便的(情形)。